# I want to get the last 25 elements of a collection in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Recently I've built a chat app using react + firebase but there's something that doesn't work quite right.

I'm able to send messages and have them stored in the firebase database. Now here's the problem: it only shows the first 25 messages that got stored.

Here's the part of the code that's problematic:

```
const messagesRef = firestore.collection("messages");
const query = messagesRef.orderBy("createdAt").limit(25);
```

Is there a way to start at the bottom from the last 25 message? Using "desc" doesn't work either because it displays the data starting from the last message at the top and I want the exact opposite.

Comment: What doesn't work the way you expect when using "desc"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase has a .limitToLast() function that you can chain on to your .collection()

```
const query = messagesRef.orderBy("createdAt").limitToLast(25);
```

[LimitToLast Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#limittolast)
[LimitToLast filtering docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

`const query = messagesRef.orderBy("createdAt", "desc").limit(25);`

Here you have more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#node.js